# Any ideas on what is causing my tiles to not fit together?

Tags: c#, xna, double

I have a tile system written in XNA, and there is problems with tiles fitting together.

What I mean is, sometimes tiles are separated by 1 pixel (maybe 2 pixels? can't tell), and they are suppose to fit together perfectly. I am certain the math I did to get them together is right, I don't know what is causing the issue.

Surprisingly this issue is fixed when I raise the size of my tiles (a double) to 1000. Size is only relative to my camera zoom, so this does not affect game play at all, but it bothers me I have to do this.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

edit: infact anything below a tile size of 995 has the issue, but anything above is good, this is some kind of weird precision issue. Is double math more accurate with high numbers or something?

Comment: Maybe show us a relevant part of your code? Or are we supposed to place our bets instead? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, pixels are integers, and if the size of your tiles are in doubles, that means you must be doing some sort of conversion to get the pixels, which in turn is probably where you are getting the separation.

For example if tile A starts at 0, and is 9.9 in length, where do you put the next tile?

Comment: it's rounded, so the first tile would be 0-10, the next would be 10 - 20, until it the addition leads to a a fraction below .5 then it is rounded down

Answer (score 0):

If you are rounding in this case you would use `Math.Round(value, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` because `Math.Round(value)` does not return what you are mathematically taught as "rounding" to be.

I can't remember the specifics but it arises things like `Math.Round(0.5) = 0` and `Math.Round(1.5) = 2`!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to diagnose without seeing how you are handling tile placement. Are your tiles fixed width and height or variable?

Here is how I lay out my level consisting of tiles of size 32x32.

- Tile class contains texture of tile and grid position of tile.
- Iterate through Tile collection and draw them at:

  - X = gridPosition.X * textureWidth
  - Y = gridPosition.Y * textureHeight

So, if you have a tile of 32x32 at grid position (0, 0), then it will be drawn at (0, 0). 
And if you have a tile of 32x32 at grid position (0, 1), then it will be drawn at (0, 32).